# Pexpect Multiple, Different Prompts

Tags: python, python-2.7, pexpect

Script-1 can be run from a shell and will ask the user for 3 prompts, A, B, and C in that order. A *or* B will appear to the user, and C will *always* will appear. In other words, when Script-1 is run, the user will be prompted by question A or B. Once answered, the question C will always be prompted last.

I want to write Script-2, which will use logic to answer prompts A, B, and C automatically in Python. Pexpect seems perfect for this, however, how would one use pexpect when there are two different prompts- A *or* B- that could be presented to it?

Thank you.

Answer (score -2):

`pexpect` allows you to specify a list of prompts to match against, so it caters explicitly to your use case.  Consult the docstring of `pexpect.expect()`.